# How to get ngmodel reference inside for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a three-dimensional array which I am looping over in my template using ng for. In the third level, I am using the ng model to get the change in the model. I have a submit button in the loop at the first level.

I am trying to access the value of the ng-model at the first level(in submit button) because I want to disable the button if all the values of the models are blank. If any of the models have value then the button will not be disabled anymore.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let zone of driverHoursZones">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="pb-2">{{ zone.zoneName }}</h5>
            <div class="table_scroll">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Driver Name</th>
                            <th
                                *ngFor="
                                    let date of dates
                                "
                            >
                                {{ date }}
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <ng-container
                            *ngFor="
                                let driver of zone.drivers
                            "
                        >
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{ driver.driverName }}
                                </td>
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngFor="
                                        let hour of driver.hours
                                    "
                                >
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="d-flex line_h">
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                mask="Hh:m0:s0"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="HH:MM:SS"
                                                [(ngModel)]="hour.hours"
                                                [dropSpecialCharacters]="false"
                                            />
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </ng-container>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            //trying to access the values of the models here
            // if all the values are blank button will be disabled
            <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-end mt-3"
                (click)="saveDriverHours($event, zone)"
            >
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The code works fine for me, the zone value is in my console. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @Jimmy, I am trying to add a disable in the button if all the values in model are blank

Comment: Then check the answer below of @jintender. What you need is a condition and put it in the attribute binding of the button ([disabled] = condition)

Comment: I think you should look at converting the whole thing to angular-forms, either reactive or template-driven. That way you have complete control when the form is valid or not and can disable buttons depending on that. Naren Murali's answer starts you off with a template driven solution that you can build on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property inside your component to check if the button should be disabled something like

```
 get isButtonDisalbed(){
    return this.driverHoursZones?.every(z=> z.drivers?.every(d=> d?.hours.every(h=> !h?.hours)))
  }
```

then on your button use this property to disable

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-end mt-3" (click)="saveDriverHours($event, zone)" [disabled]="isButtonDisalbed">
  Save
</button>
```

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twi96c?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, is it not going to create any performance issues, because all my lists can have so many data

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the solution, subscribe to form value changes, then set the disabled attribute property, so that its a bit more performant!

ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({ selector: 'app', templateUrl: 'app.component.html' })
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('testForm') testForm: NgForm;
  disabled = true;
  driverHoursZones: any = [
    {
      zoneName: 'test',
      drivers: [
        {
          driverName: 'test',
          hours: [
            { hours: 1 },
            { hours: 2 },
            { hours: 3 },
            { hours: 4 },
            { hours: 5 },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  dates = new Array(5).map((x) => new Date());

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.testForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.disabled = false;
      for (let key in this.testForm.form.controls) {
        const value = this.testForm.form.controls[key];
        if (value && value.errors && value.errors.required) {
          this.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let zone of driverHoursZones">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="pb-2">{{ zone.zoneName }}</h5>
      <div class="table_scroll">
        <form #testForm="ngForm">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Driver Name</th>
                <th *ngFor="let date of dates">
                  {{ date }}
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let driver of zone.drivers">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {{ driver.driverName }}
                  </td>
                  <ng-container
                    *ngFor="let hour of driver.hours; let i = index"
                  >
                    <td>
                      <span class="d-flex line_h">
                        <input
                          required
                          [id]="zone.zoneName + driver.driverName + 'hours' + i"
                          [name]="
                            zone.zoneName + driver.driverName + 'hours' + i
                          "
                          type="text"
                          mask="Hh:m0:s0"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="HH:MM:SS"
                          [(ngModel)]="hour.hours"
                        />
                      </span>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>
                </tr>
              </ng-container>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
      //trying to access the values of the models here // if all the values are
      blank button will be disabled
      <button
        [disabled]="disabled"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-end mt-3"
        (click)="saveDriverHours($event, zone)"
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-template-driven-form-validation-wezvwj)